# Mongoose model not saving for some reason

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-auto-increment

I've create a Mongoose model and I wrote some code to test if it works, I tried to save the model and then display all of the models but it doesn't log anything to the console and the model isn't saving.

My testing code:

```
let User = require('./models/user')(MAI);
let myUser = new User({
  username: 'Admin',
  email: 'admin@example.com',
  password: '123456',
});

await myUser.save();

User.find((err, users) => {
  if(err) console.log(err);
  console.dir(users);
});
```

My model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  user_id: Number,
  username: String,
  email: String,
  password: String,
  verified: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  joindate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  postcount: { type: Number, default: 0 },
});

module.exports = function(MAI) {
  UserSchema.plugin(MAI.plugin, {
    model: 'User',
    field: 'user_id',
    startAt: 1,
    incrementBy: 1,
    unique: true
  });
  return mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
}
```

And if it's important, mongoose & mai initialization:

```
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
let connection = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017/forum');
MAI.initialize(connection);
```

Comment: You're sure it's not saving? You checked with the `mongo` cli?

Comment: Well if it's not logging anything than it's not saving...

Comment: That's incorrect. Your code is written as if `save` is synchronous. It is not.

Comment: Changed my test and it still doesn't work, and yes, the function that runs the test code is async.

Comment: afaik the find method takes an query object as first argument and not a cb so your cb it gets never called as its interpreted as the query object

Comment: Nope, in the docs it says that if you pass only a cb it will fetch everything, but just to be sure I've added an empty object as a query and it still doesn't work, the problem is with the saving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, the problem was I required mongoose in the model file when what I should've done was to pass the mongoose from my entry point.